# Find nearest value in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a dataframe like below,

```
     0           1               2               3               4
0   (989, 998)  (1074, 999)     (1159, 1000)    (1244, 1001)    (1329, 1002)
1   (970, 1042) (1057, 1043)    (1143, 1044)    (1230, 1045)    (1316, 1046)
2   (951, 1088) (1039, 1089)    (1127, 1090)    (1214, 1091)    (1302, 1092)
3   (930, 1137) (1020, 1138)    (1109, 1139)    (1198, 1140)    (1287, 1141)
4   (909, 1188) (1000, 1189)    (1091, 1190)    (1181, 1191)    (1271, 1192)
```

Each cell has x and y coordinates in tuple. I have an input called I and that's also x and Y coordinate in a tuple. My goal is to find the nearest point for input I.

Sample Input:

`(1080, 1000)`

Sample Output:

`(1074, 999)`

I have tried the below snippet.

```
def find_nearest(array, key):
    min_ = 1000
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for item in array:
        diff = abs(item[0]-key[0])+abs(item[1]-key[1])
        if diff<min_:
            min_ = diff
            a,b = item
        if diff==0:
            return (a,b)
    return (a,b)
find_nearest(sum(df.values.tolist(), []), I)
```

This gives me what I expected. But, Is there any efficient solution for the problem?

Comment: I really appreciate all the efforts. Thanks u so much guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
# Setup
data = [[(989, 998), (1074, 999), (1159, 1000), (1244, 1001), (1329, 1002)],
        [(970, 1042), (1057, 1043), (1143, 1044), (1230, 1045), (1316, 1046)],
        [(951, 1088), (1039, 1089), (1127, 1090), (1214, 1091), (1302, 1092)],
        [(930, 1137), (1020, 1138), (1109, 1139), (1198, 1140), (1287, 1141)],
        [(909, 1188), (1000, 1189), (1091, 1190), (1181, 1191), (1271, 1192)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

l = (1080, 1000)

out = min(df.to_numpy().flatten(), key=lambda c: (c[0]- l[0])**2 + (c[1]-l[1])**2)
print(out)

# Output:
(1074, 999)
```

**Update**:

> Is there any way, I can get df index of nearest element?

```
dist = df.stack().apply(lambda c: (c[0]- l[0])**2 + (c[1]-l[1])**2)
idx = dist.index[dist.argmin()]
val = df.loc[idx]

print(idx)
print(val)

# Output:
(0, 1)
(1074, 999)
```

**Update 2**

> But, Is there any efficient solution for the problem?

```
arr = df.to_numpy().astype([('x', int), ('y', int)])
dist = (arr['x'] - l[0])**2 + (arr['y'] - l[1])**2
idx = tuple(np.argwhere(dist == np.min(dist))[0])
val = arr[idx]  # or df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any way, I can get df index of nearest element?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: once again thanks @Corralien

Answer (score 1):

How about this snippet I wrote?

```
# cordinates: np.ndarray(n, 2)
def find_nearest(cordinates, x, y):
    x_d = np.abs(cordinate[:, 0] - x)
    y_d = np.abs(cordinate[:, 1] - y)
    nearest_idx = np.argmin(x_d  + y_d)
    return cordinate[nearest_idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use swifter and applymap for faster processing

```
I = (1080, 1000)

diff = df.swifter.applymap(lambda item: abs(item[0]-I[0])+abs(item[1]-I[1]))

col_index = diff.min(axis=0)[diff.min(axis=0) == diff.min(axis=0).min()].index[0]
row_index = diff.min(axis=1)[diff.min(axis=1) == diff.min(axis=1).min()].index[0]

df.loc[row_index, col_index]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance

data = [(989, 998), (1074, 999), (1159, 1000), (1244, 1001), (1329, 1002),
        (970, 1042), (1057, 1043), (1143, 1044), (1230, 1045), (1316, 1046),
        (951, 1088), (1039, 1089), (1127, 1090), (1214, 1091), (1302, 1092),
        (930, 1137), (1020, 1138), (1109, 1139), (1198, 1140), (1287, 1141),
        (909, 1188), (1000, 1189), (1091, 1190), (1181, 1191), (1271, 1192)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
def find_nearest( df, x, y):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    index_of_closest = -1
    for index, pos in enumerate(df.values):
        x_coord, y_coord = pos
        current_distance = distance.euclidean((x, y), (x_coord, y_coord))
        if current_distance < min_distance and current_distance != 0 :
            min_distance = current_distance
            index_of_nearest= index
    return index_of_nearest

print("index=",find_nearest(df,1080, 1000),"value=",data[find_nearest(df,1080, 1000)])
```

or this way and it will give the nearest for every element and you need to sort thm.

```
df.iloc[-1]=[1080, 1000]
z = np.array([[complex(c[0], c[1]) for c in df.values]])
Distance = abs(z.T - z)
distance = Distance
masked_a = np.ma.masked_equal(distance, 0.0, copy=False)
index=np.argmin(masked_a[:, len(masked_a)-1])
print("index=",index,"value=",df.loc[index])
```

**Update**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance
import timeit

data = [(989, 998), (1074, 999), (1159, 1000), (1244, 1001), (1329, 1002),
        (970, 1042), (1057, 1043), (1143, 1044), (1230, 1045), (1316, 1046),
        (951, 1088), (1039, 1089), (1127, 1090), (1214, 1091), (1302, 1092),
        (930, 1137), (1020, 1138), (1109, 1139), (1198, 1140), (1287, 1141),
        (909, 1188), (1000, 1189), (1091, 1190), (1181, 1191), (1271, 1192)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
def find_nearest( df, x, y):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    index_of_closest = -1
    for index, pos in enumerate(df.values):
        x_coord, y_coord = pos
        current_distance = distance.euclidean((x, y), (x_coord, y_coord))
        if current_distance < min_distance and current_distance != 0 :
            min_distance = current_distance
            index_of_nearest= index
    return index_of_nearest
starttime = timeit.default_timer()
print(data[find_nearest(df,1080, 1000)])
print("The time difference 1 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
#or
starttime = timeit.default_timer()
df.iloc[-1]=[1080, 1000]
z = np.array([[complex(c[0], c[1]) for c in df.values]])
Distance = abs(z.T - z)
masked_a = np.ma.masked_equal(Distance, 0.0, copy=False)
print(df.iloc[np.argmin(masked_a[:, len(masked_a)-1])])
print("The time difference 2 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

data = [[(989, 998), (1074, 999), (1159, 1000), (1244, 1001), (1329, 1002)],
        [(970, 1042), (1057, 1043), (1143, 1044), (1230, 1045), (1316, 1046)],
        [(951, 1088), (1039, 1089), (1127, 1090), (1214, 1091), (1302, 1092)],
        [(930, 1137), (1020, 1138), (1109, 1139), (1198, 1140), (1287, 1141)],
        [(909, 1188), (1000, 1189), (1091, 1190), (1181, 1191), (1271, 1192)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
starttime = timeit.default_timer()
l = (1080, 1000)
out = min(df.to_numpy().flatten(), key=lambda c: (c[0]- l[0])**2 + (c[1]-l[1])**2)
print(out)
print("The time difference for method 3 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()
dist = df.stack().apply(lambda c: (c[0]- l[0])**2 + (c[1]-l[1])**2)
idx = dist.index[dist.argmin()]
val = df.loc[idx]

print(idx)
print(val)
print("The time difference for method 4 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()
arr = df.to_numpy().astype([('x', int), ('y', int)])
dist = (arr['x'] - l[0])**2 + (arr['y'] - l[1])**2
idx = tuple(np.argwhere(dist == np.min(dist))[0])
val = arr[idx]  # or df.loc[idx]
print(val)
print("The time difference for method 5 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()
I = (1080, 1000)

s1 = df.stack()
s = pd.DataFrame(s1.to_list(), index=s1.index).sub(I).pow(2).sum(axis=1)
out = s[s.idxmin()]
print (out)
(1074, 999)

print(s.idxmin())
(0, '1')
print("The time difference for method 6 is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
```

From all answers, I found that [Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70418676/4694757) answer is the fastest.

[image]

**Update 2**

However, in a larger Dataframe, it starts to dropdown:

[image]

Comment: hmmm, maybe best is test in larger Dataframe, in 5 rows, 5 columns is to small data for test.

Comment: You are right because, in my answers, I use the second answer because it is faster but now it is worse than my first answer. However, I used to find the nearest for all matrices.

Comment: Ya, try use 100k rows and then performance should be different, maybe not, no idea.

Comment: You are right it is affected more than the other `0.0002272040001116693` while `0.0009154750150628388`

Answer (score 1):

Solution with filtered by some minimal value `min_`, solution is create `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `Dataframe` constructor, then subract `I`, power [`DataFrame.pow`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) and `sum`, last for indices is used [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
I = (1080, 1000)

min_ = 1000
s1 = df.stack()
s = pd.DataFrame(s1.to_list(), index=s1.index).sub(I).pow(2).sum(axis=1)
s = s[s < min_]

out = (0, 0) if s.empty else s[s.idxmin()]
print (out)
```

For indices:

```
idx = 'no match' if s.empty else s.idxmin()
print (idx)
(0, '1')
```

If dont need filtering:

```
I = (1080, 1000)

s1 = df.stack()
s = pd.DataFrame(s1.to_list(), index=s1.index).sub(I).pow(2).sum(axis=1)
out = s[s.idxmin()]
print (out)
(1074, 999)

print(s.idxmin())
(0, '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you just need a two-column DataFrame and find distance between each row and a sample coordinate. So here is my implementation:

Your data when copied came off as strings. You don't actually need this line:

```
data = pd.Series(df.to_numpy().flatten()).str.strip().str.strip('()').str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int)
sample = (1080, 1000)
```

Solution start here:

```
distances = data.apply(lambda x: (x[0]-sample[0])**2+(x[1]-sample[1])**2, axis=1)
out = tuple(data[distances == distances.min()].to_numpy()[0])
```

Output:

```
(1074, 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [nmslib](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib) library which enables you to do K-Nearest-Neighbor Searching. Have a look at the [example](https://nmslib.github.io/nmslib/quickstart.html) and you could easily implement such a system.

PS It could be kind of overkill for a simple program but nevertheless it is a good, easy and especially fast way of solving your problem!