# Find nearest value in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this isotope masses list: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Compositions/stand_alone.pl?ele=&all=all&ascii=ascii&isotype=all

for example

```
Element     Isotope     Relative Atomic Mass    Isotopic Composition    Standard Atomic Weight
0   H          NaN               NaN               NaN                     NaN
1   NaN     1   1.00782503223(9)    0.999885(70)    [1.00784,1.00811]
2   NaN     2   2.01410177812(12)   0.000115(70)    NaN
3   NaN     3   3.0160492779(24)    NaN     NaN
4   NaN     4   4.02643(11)     NaN     NaN
5   NaN     5   5.035311(96)    NaN     NaN
6   NaN     6   6.04496(27)     NaN     NaN
7   NaN     7   7.0527(11#)     NaN     NaN
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9   He      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  NaN     3   3.0160293201(25)    0.00000134(3)   4.002602(2)
11  NaN     4   4.00260325413(6)    0.99999866(3)   NaN
12  NaN     5   5.012057(21)    NaN     NaN
13  NaN     6   6.018885891(57)     NaN     NaN
14  NaN     7   7.0279907(81)   NaN     NaN
15  NaN     8   8.033934390(95)     NaN     NaN
16  NaN     9   9.043946(50)    NaN     NaN
17  NaN     10  10.05279(11)    NaN     NaN
18  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
19  Li      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
20  NaN     3   3.0308(21#)     [6.938,6.997]   m
21  NaN     4   4.02719(23)     NaN     NaN
22  NaN     5   5.012538(54)    NaN     NaN
23  NaN     6   6.0151228874(16)    0.0759(4)   NaN
24  NaN     7   7.0160034366(45)    0.9241(4)   NaN
25  NaN     8   8.022486246(50)     NaN     NaN
26  NaN     9   9.02679019(20)  NaN     NaN
27  NaN     10  10.035483(14)   NaN     NaN
28  NaN     11  11.04372358(66)     NaN     NaN
29  NaN     12  12.052517(16)   NaN     NaN
```

Now I want to do some calculations with measured data, for example a mass bias correction:

```
7Li/6Li_corrected = 7Li/6Li * ((7.0160034366 / 6.0151228874) ** True_value
```

How can I find the 7.0160034366 or 6.0151228874 depending on the column name ("7Li/6Li") in a dataframe?

I thought about a "find nearest" like here: [Find nearest value in dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418576/find-nearest-value-in-dataframe) but I need a way to identify the isotope of interest (7Li and 6Li). How can I do that?
The problem I see with "nearest neighbor" is when I want to do the same calculation for `7He/6He` that 6Li is closer to 6 than 6He `(6.018885891 vs 6.0151228874).` Thus, I need to read the list up to the next row containing an Element name.

Edit: I formatted the list since pandas couldn't read it.

Comment: Since that isn't a standard table, show how you have created the dataframe. Use `df.head(10).to_clipboard(excel=False)` to copy the first 10 rows of your dataframe to clipboard (as text) which you can then paste into your question. Short version is you'll have to do something like `df[df["element"] == "Li") & (df["isotope"] == 6)]` which would give you the whole row for 6Li. Then you pick the mass with the column name: `df[df["element"] == "Li") & (df["isotope"] == 6)]["Relative Mass"]`

Comment: Thx, but .to_clipboard doesn't work since it is an headless jupyterlab server. But your approach just results in an empty output. I edited the question with the dataframe.